# System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid. at System.Drawing.Bitmap with FastReport pdf export

Tags: .net, fastreport

Consistently receiving the error mentioned in the title on one of my machines when attempting to perform the SimplePdfExport. With the SimplePdfExport the pdf is rendered as an image hence the use of the bitmap constructor. The report itself does not contain any images. Other machines don't have this problem - right now its isolated to just one. I've attached the full stacktrace below.

Seems to have 'randomly' started. No recent changes to the offending computer or the report file. Any insight in to this? I've dug through the SimplePdfExport source code and not seeing any way to avoid this issue or what could be causing it.

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at FastReport.Export.PdfSimple.PDFSimpleExport.ExportPageBegin(ReportPage page)
   at FastReport.Export.ExportBase.ExportPageNew(Int32 pageNo)
   at FastReport.Export.ExportBase.Export(Report report, Stream stream)
```

Comment: upgraded PdfSimple from `2020.3.22` to `2023.2.29` and the issue seems to be fixed for now.